# OpenGL transformation

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, transformation

I want to ask a question about transformation.

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0.0, -10, 0.0);
glScalef(5000.0, 10.0, 5000.0);
glPushMatrix();
glColor3f(0,0,0);
glutSolidCube(1);
glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glutWireCube(1);
glPopMatrix();
glPopMatrix();
```

The above code is the one I wrote to create a cube. In this case, I have understood the centre of the cube will be on y = -5. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Can you elaborate why you think the cube should be at y=5? There is no 5 in the y axis transformations.

Answer (score 0):

One of the great things about computer graphics is that you can always run the program and *see* what happens. And then swap the order of the translate and scale calls and run it again. You'll figure it out.

In this case, you may have difficulties because there's no reference to compare the cube to. I often use a little `drawAxes()` function, and recommend it to students, that just draws three lines from 0,0,0 to each of X=1, Y=1, Z=1. (Helps to draw the X line in red, Y in green, Z in blue.) Draw the axes as the very first thing you do so you've got a reference point, draw them again anytime you're not sure where a series of transformations will end up.